# Array Data File Operations

Tags: java

I need to print the data out that has been inputted from the user using datainputstream
    and dataoutputstream but this is not even taking the inputs properly.Can anyone tell me
    what is wrong with my code?

```
import java.io.*;

class Employee
 {
int id;
String name;
double salary;
 }

public class Ch8Ex2 
 {
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      Employee emp = new Employee();
      try
       {
         File f1 = new File("emp1.dat");
         f1.createNewFile();

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         DataInputStream da = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f1));
         DataOutputStream ad = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f1));

         System.out.println("Enter your ID:");
         emp.id = br.read();
         System.out.println("Enter your name:");
         emp.name = br.readLine();
         System.out.println("Enter your salary:");
         String str = br.readLine();
         emp.salary = Double.parseDouble(str);

         ad.write(emp.id);
         ad.writeUTF(emp.name);
         ad.writeDouble(emp.salary);

         ad.flush();
         ad.close();

         System.out.println("ID:"+da.readInt());

         System.out.println("Name:"+da.readUTF());

         System.out.println("Salary:"+da.readDouble());

         da.close();
       }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {

        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ad.writeInt(emp.id)` because `ad.write(int)` only writes a single byte.

Comment: Such small mistakes make me mad Dx thank you so much...its all fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is the only thing

```
emp.id = br.read();
```

should be

```
emp.id = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

`BufferedReader.read()` [reads a single character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29)

Unless of course `id` is just a single character.

Comment: Thank youuu :D The inputs are being taken properly now...but it is still not showing the values entered.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Employee` must be Serializable

```
 class Employee implements Serializable
 {
   int id;
   String name;
   double salary;
 }
```

also print exception in catch block then you can get what is wrong.

Comment: Ok I made it serializable but I am still getting the same problem. It takes the employee id but then asks for both the name ans salary together. I type some name and then it gives numberformatexception.